# Send SMS using OpenVox Gateway C#

Tags: c#

We have OpenVox PBX System here in our office.
i need to create an apps that can send sms using our api.
but always getting error.

[Send SMS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSK2p.png)

- Sim has a Load.
- HTTP

String URL: http://172.16.6.8:443/sendsms?username=xxx&password=xxx&phonenumber=xxx&message=xxx&[port=xxx&][report=xxx&][timeout=xxx]

[String URL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKxoC.png)

here my settings.

- http://172.16.6.8:443/send/
- username: core
- password: core2017
- phonenumber: 09954293534
- message: Testing from c# Code
- port: gsm-1.1
- report: String
- timeout: 5

[My Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg7LX.png)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code in the question itself. Code shared via image is not readable. What error message you are getting? Are they real credentials of the service? It's not at all recommended to share the real credentials on SO. Please remove them or put some junk there..

Comment: thanks @ChetanRanpariya I already fix my problem. its all about my string url, thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your Url is incorrect:
it should be: http://172.16.6.8:443/sendsms?
you have set http://172.16.6.8/send/